# composer handoff transcript

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

How to pass to library which implement handoff request based on [community example](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Components.Handoff.ServiceNow) full bot transcript, which happen before "Send Handoff request" initiated?
Logically Context object is suitable place to pass transcript history

Comment: hi -- additional info is needed. Can you clearify what do you mean by "How to pass to library which implement handoff request"?

Comment: We developed handoff library using Bot.Builder.Community.Components.Handoff interface - https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/develop/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Components.Handoff.ServiceNow
In documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/concept-agent-handoff exist statement "provide a JSON object within the Context property input box in the right hand pane. " so my question is how in composer obtain current conversation transcript and pass it via Context property

Comment: @RamFattah any update?

Comment: you can use Memory scopes and properties to track your bot's active conversation state and send it via context property. Official docs for Memory scopes and properties here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/ref-memory-variables?tabs=v2x